# What is segmentation fault (core dumped) mean?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm relatively new to C and I don't understand what this means. I get the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error when I try and run the code below. The purpose to just to make a "map" of nodes. The nodes can possibly have three pointers to another node, some have all three some do not. If they don't, I have the pointer in the struct point to NULL. I made a function that returns a `node_ptr`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node *node_ptr;

struct Node {
    char ch;
    node_ptr firstPtr;
    node_ptr secondPtr;
    node_ptr thirdPtr;
};

node_ptr makeNode(char any, node_ptr x, node_ptr y, node_ptr z){
        node_ptr temp; 
        temp->ch = any;
        temp->firstPtr = x;
        temp->secondPtr = y;
        temp->thirdPtr = z;

        return temp;
}

int main(){
    printf("Making a map.....");

node_ptr A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H;

A = makeNode('A', B, NULL, NULL);
B = makeNode('B', A, C, F);
C = makeNode('C', B, D, NULL);
D = makeNode('D', C, E, NULL);
E = makeNode('E', D, NULL, NULL);
F = makeNode('F', B, G, H);
G = makeNode('G', F, NULL, NULL);
H = makeNode('H', F, NULL, NULL);

return 0;
 }
```

What exactly caused this segmentation fault and what does it mean? Also, can a solution be offered up to fix this code snippet here?

Comment: You are not allocating memory to node_ptr in makenode.

Comment: segmentation fault (seg fault for short) is caused when you try to de-reference an uninitialized pointer. So if you have a pointer `node_ptr temp;` and you try to do `temp->ch = any;`, you get seg fault. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Causes) for other ways this is caused

Comment: "if you have a pointer node_ptr temp; and you try to do temp->ch = any;, you get seg fault" - not necessarily. It is uninitialised, so it might point to any location - maybe valid one, maybe not, but surely not "free" one - overwriting it will cause problems.

Answer (score 4):

It means you're accessing memory that you aren't allowed to access. Here, you are making a pointer to a node at the beginning of makeNode(), but you aren't pointing it at anything. It could be pointing anywhere. Then you try filling the thing it is pointing at with values, but wherever it happens to be pointing is a place you don't have access to (it could be an area of memory that is being used for something else).

What you want to do is allocate memory for a node, point your node pointer to that memory, and then fill that with values and return it. Something like:

```
node_ptr makeNode(char any, node_ptr x, node_ptr y, node_ptr z){
        node_ptr temp = (node_ptr) malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
        temp->ch = any;
        temp->firstPtr = x;
        temp->secondPtr = y;
        temp->thirdPtr = z;

        return temp;
}
```

Then make sure to deallocate this memory when you no longer need it, with a call to `free()`:

```
free(A);
free(B);
free(C);
... etc. ...
```

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but how do you know when you need to allocate memory in the heap vs. when it will be put on the stack? Is it because I am creating a node that is used in two functions and when that function is over, the pointer is lost and it doesn't return?

Comment: @JeremyRuten I would add that `A = makeNode('A', B, NULL, NULL);` won't work because `B` hasn't been initialized at that point in the code.

Comment: @user3268401 you never created node on stack, only pointer to it, that points to <somewhere unspecified>. But anyway, you cannot reliably return pointer to function-local variable because it might be overwritten on next function call (not just this function - any one).

Comment: Yes, anything you allocate on the stack will disappear when the function ends. So if you allocate the node on the stack, you don't want to return a pointer to it. You could allocate on the stack, and return the node itself (instead of a pointer), which would basically copy the whole node from makeNode()'s part of the stack to main()'s part of the stack. But passing pointers is a lot cheaper than passing large structs, which is why you usually allocate a struct on the heap and pass back a pointer to it.